# Trouble with nested resource routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working off the starter site that you can find [here](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site), and I'm attempting to get nested resource routes working. I have projects which contain many versions, and both the project and version URLs need the usual view/edit/delete functions. I've set up my routes like this:

```
    # Project Management
    Route::get('projects/{project}', 'AdminProjectsController@getShow');
    Route::get('projects/{project}/edit', 'AdminProjectsController@getEdit');
    Route::post('projects/{project}/edit', 'AdminProjectsController@postEdit');
    Route::get('projects/{project}/delete', 'AdminProjectsController@getDelete');
    Route::post('projects/{project}/delete', 'AdminProjectsController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('projects', 'AdminProjectsController');

    # Version Management
    Route::get('projects/{project}/versions/{version}', 'AdminVersionsController@getShow');
    Route::get('projects/{project}/versions/{version}/edit', 'AdminVersionsController@getEdit');
    Route::post('projects/{project}/versions/{version}/edit', 'AdminVersionsController@postEdit');
    Route::get('projects/{project}/versions/{version}/delete', 'AdminVersionsController@getDelete');
    Route::post('projects/{project}/versions/{version}/delete', 'AdminVersionsController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('projects.versions', 'AdminVersionsController');
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I go to a url like `/projects/1/versions/1` I'm getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.
```

and the getShow() method of the AdminVersionsController does exist and looks like this:

```
class AdminVersionsController extends AdminController {
    ....
    public function getShow($project, $version) {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

I also get the same error for every other URL related to the versions. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your url is caught by this restful routes set (the one called _missing):

```
Route::controller('projects', 'AdminProjectsController');

// the route is this:
GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE projects/{_missing}
```

and what you want for nested resources is:

```
Route::resource('projects.versions', 'AdminProjectsController');
```

Then in that controller you need to rename your methods to match those of resource controllers: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean. I don't think that simply switching out `Route::controller('projects.versions', 'AdminVersionsController');` for `Route::resource('projects.versions', 'AdminProjectsController');` is going to solve my problem, so could you expand on your answer?

Comment: Run 'artisan routes' in console to check what routes you have now defined, then change it as I wrote and check again. Basically restful controllers (what yuou have now) always have by default _missing route. Moreover you can't nest those as you'd like.

Comment: When I run `artisan routes`, the route is there: `GET|HEAD admin/projects/{project}/versions/{version}                  | | AdminVersionsController@getShow`.